# Ruby : What is the difference between " a = nil || 2008 " and " a = nil or 2008 "

Tags: ruby

When I evaluate the expression `a = nil || 2008` in Irb, I get the answer as **2008** and `a` is assigned the value **2008** which is correct as `||` operator return their first argument unless it is `false` or `nil`.

But when I do something like `a = nil or 2008` on Irb console, `a` is assigned `nil` and the return value of the evaluation of the expression I get is still **2008**.

Has it got something to do with operator precedence. I was just wondering why it works this way, can someone please shed some light on this ?

Comment: These operators have different precedence. In such expressions always use `||` (unless you know you *need* `or` there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of precedence in your cases is following(from higher to lower):

1. `||`
2. `=`
3. `or`

So here `a = nil || 2008`

- Operation 1: `nil || 2008`
- Operation 2: `a = Operation 1`

and for `a = nil or 2008`

- Operation 1: `a = nil`
- Operation 2: `Operation 1 or 2008` which returns 2008, because Operation 1 is `nil`

Comment: Thanks Rustam, the step by step explanation helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 5):

`||` and `or` have different precedences. This was meant to be used, e.g. for error handling:

```
foo = do_something_which_could_fail_and_return_nil_then(...) or deal_with_error(...)
```

Some people think [it should be avoided](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or),  i.e. `or` and `and` should not be used at all.

Comment: “Some people“ made my day.

Comment: Thanks undur_gongor, Link to ruby style guide was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You answered it yourself. It is due to operator precedence. || has higher precedence then = and  "or" has lower precedence then '='.
Here is a [precedence table for ruby operators](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4)

if you use

```
a = (nil or 2008)
```

then it will give same result as

```
a = nil || 2008
```